# ANSI SQL for links

Tags: sql-standard, dblink

Oracle provides a "link" mechanism in order to access a different database instance than the one on which the query is running.

DIM_DATES@OTHERDB

Is there any ANSI SQL standard way to code this?

Comment: You're talking about Oracle DB links? Good question by the way. But i don't think that it has an ANSI similar command, cause it's based on Oracle TNS ...

Comment: Yes, referring to Oracle DB links. I found that it can refer to other database types if Oracle Heterogeneous Services is used.

Is there any way to accomplish an equivalent using ANSI SQL standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL/MED (Management of External Data) is an extension to SQL standard defined by ISO/IEC 9075-9:2008. SQL/MED foreign-data wrappers can be used to refer to external RDBMS and non-RDBMS data sources.

While I don't think Oracle or MS SQL Server support SQL/MED, DB2 and PostgreSQL are supporting SQL/MED.